# Ethernet connection ignored Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet

Suddenly the eth0 have changed its name in enx00e04c69e0b3 and I can't connect to the Ethernet. The wifi works fine.

Ubuntu 16.04
XPS 13-9370

ifconfig:

```
enx00e04c69e0b3 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:69:e0:b3  
          inet6 addr: fe80::87c2:119a:1025:3852/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1012 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:204 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:117772 (117.7 KB)  TX bytes:38698 (38.6 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:719 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:719 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:112488 (112.4 KB)  TX bytes:112488 (112.4 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:b6:d0:8c:99:cd  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17098 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2429 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6185434 (6.1 MB)  TX bytes:323774 (323.7 KB)
```

In /etc/network/interfaces i have just this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

What can I do?

Comment: Are you getting a link light on your machine at the ethernet port? On the router? Can you try a different cable? You also need to disable the wifi while you are trying this as it may not default to Ethernet on its own. Your not getting an ip address on that interface for some reason. As for why the name changed, I'm not sure. What's the last significant thing you did to the machine? Installed a new application or modified some drivers or kernel settings? Ran updates?

Comment: Yes I'm getting a link light from the router. I tried a different cable and a different port, but the same problem. I ran an update yesterday before all this to happen